# Perché si dice 'fare alla romana'?

Tags: idioms

Fare alla romana, riferito alla divisione di un conto da pagare (in genere del ristorante), significa dividere in parti uguali. Che origine ha questo modo di dire? È un'espressione usata sia al nord che al sud o ha una connotazione geografica?

Comment: http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/pagare-romana

Answer (score 3):

Ho trovato questa spiegazione nel libro *Acqua in bocca! Tutto quello che vorresti dire in italiano... come lo direbbe un italiano!* di Roberto Bortoluzzi (Casa delle lingue, Barcellona, 2015):

> **Fare alla romana**
>
> Significa dividere in parti uguali una spesa, soprattutto il conto del ristorante. L'aggettivo *romana* deriva, molto probabilmente, dalle gite fuori Roma, in cui si facevano delle merende abbondanti e ogni partecipante pagava la propria quota.

Questa spiegazione concorda con quello che appare nell'[articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/pagare-romana) menzionato da @WalterTross.

Comment: Interessante ma curioso, che fosse un'usanza soltanto dei romani?

Comment: @Josh61: Nell'articolo della Crusca si spiega la probabile relazione col vocabolo *romanata*, ormai in disuso.

Answer (score 2):

Buon giorno.

Io vengo dal nord Italia e fare alla romana non vuol dire dividere in parti uguali, ma ognuno per se, cioè ognuno paga quello che ha realmente consumato.

Vista la domanda, quindi, l'espressione ha sicuramente una connotazione geografica e un significato diverso in funzione a dove viene detta.

Comment: Leggendo in giro (oltre che nella mia esperienza), l'uso più diffuso sembra essere quello spiegato dall'OP, ossia dividere in parti uguali.

Comment: Un articolo della Crusca: http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/pagare-romana

Answer (score 1):

Non ho purtroppo fonti per confermare la mia impressione, quindi prenda questa spiegazione con precauzione.

Mi pare che l'uso di dividere in parti uguali il conto al ristorante si diffonda a partire dagli anni '60, come alternativa a quello in cui uno invita in anticipo e offre la cena a tutti, caratteristico di una epoca precedente, in cui il ristorante era frequentato maggiormente da classi più abbienti e con regole di comportamento più formali. Dagli anni del boom economico cenare al ristorante  diventa  più frequente e socialmente più diffuso, e spesso si fa in modo non programmato (per esempio, con tavolate di persone raccolte dopo il cinema). In questa situazione, continuare a invitare tutti diviene problematico (per la spesa imprevista, non "socialmente" utile,  e per gli antipatici confronti di gerarchia sociale). La soluzione pratica di dividere in parti uguali viene allora detta *alla romana*, probabilmente dal luogo di origine di questo uso, ma anche con intento di sciogliere l'imbarazzo, appellandosi alla autorità della capitale "a Roma si fa  così, sono uomini di mondo".

Invece in Italia l'uso di pagare ciascuno la propria consumazione è successivo e ancora non molto diffuso; personalmente per anni l'ho incontrato solo a New York --dove le condizioni economiche e le abitudini di vita lo rendono comprensibile.

Comment: La spiegazione del "a Roma si fa così, sono uomini di mondo" mi pare un po' cozzare contro la diffusione che l'espressione ha a Roma.

Comment: forse un po' sì